# How to create separate builds for Server and Client

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm developing an encrypted chat server, and in the Eclipse project I have them both in the same project, the server and client files are in their respective packages.

For example, server files are in a package like `org.mysite.server` and client classes are in `org.mysite.client`.

I have them all in the same project since a lot of the decryption/encryption use the same classes and methods.

How can I make builds (JARs) only containing the certain packages for either the server or client with Eclipse?

Comment: i recommend you to create a separate project for common files and include that jar in you client and server projet

Comment: @zuxqoj I'll have to look into that. I've never used them before, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create separate projects for them anyway. You can put the common classes into a third "common" or "shared" project and add it as a dependency to both the server and client project. This has the advantage that it is well supported and natural in build tools like Maven.

However, if you'd rather have everything in the same project, you may choose the files, packages and classes that go into a JAR in the *JAR Export* dialog of Eclipse: *File -> Export -> Java -> Jar File* when it say "Select the resources to export".

Comment: Is there a way I could save my settings so I wouldn't have to check the files each time using this method?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Also, if you ever switch to a build tool like Maven, I think it will get rather cumbersome too. (Whereas the "common" project strategy is very natural in Maven.) Therefore, I suggest you try the first option.